# SQL SUM operation of multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have the following mysql database table designed,

```
ticket(id, code, cust_name);
passenger(id, ticket_id, name, age, gender, fare);
service(id, passenger_id, item, cost);
```

A ticket can have many passenger and each passenger can have multiple services purchased. What I want is to get the grand total of each ticket cost.

I have tried the following sql,

```
SELECT 
    SUM(fare) as total_fare,
    (SELECT SUM(cost) as total_cost FROM services WHERE passenger.id = services.passenger_id) as total_service_cost
FROM
    ticket
JOIN passenger ON passenger.ticket_id = ticket.id
```

Though, the result gets the total of passenger fare as total_fare but for the service cost, it sums and returns the first passenger's total service cost only.

I thinks i need some more nesting of queries, need help and if possible please how can i get the result as grand total summing up both passenger fare and service cost total.

OK here is the sql insert statment to clarify,

---

```
INSERT INTO `ticket` (`id`, `code`, `cust_name`) VALUES
(1, 'TK01', 'Dipendra Gurung');

INSERT INTO `passenger` (`id`, `ticket_id`, `name`, `age`, `gender`, `fare`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'John', '28', 'M', 120),
(2, 1, 'Kelly', '25', 'F', 120);

INSERT INTO `services` (`id`, `passenger_id`, `item`, `cost`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'S1', 30),
(2, 1, 'S2', 50),
(3, 2, 'S3', 50);
```

I want to get the total cost of the ticket 'TK01' (including total fare and services total). The sql must return total fare as 120+120 = 240 and total services as 30+50+50 = 130.

Thanks! :)

Comment: How do you distinguish between services that were sold to the same passenger in different tickets? It looks like `ticket_id` is missing in `service` table...

Comment: Peterm the service table is used here, to store the service item bought by a passenger and is related to passenger table via passenger_id foreigh key constraint.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all in your current table schema you have no way to distinguish between services that have been sold to the same passenger in different tickets. Therefore you have no way to correctly calculate `total_cost` per ticket. You have to have `ticket_id` in your `service` table.

Now, if you were to have a `ticket_id` in `service` table then a solution with a correlated subqueries might look like

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT SUM(fare) 
          FROM passenger
         WHERE ticket_id = t.id) total_fare,
       (SELECT SUM(cost) 
          FROM service
         WHERE ticket_id = t.id) total_cost
  FROM ticket t
```

or with `JOIN`s

```
SELECT t.id, 
       p.fare total_fare,
       s.cost total_cost
FROM ticket t LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT ticket_id, SUM(fare) fare
    FROM passenger
   GROUP BY ticket_id
) p 
  ON t.id = p.ticket_id LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT ticket_id, SUM(cost) cost
    FROM service
   GROUP BY ticket_id
) s
  ON t.id = s.ticket_id
```

**Note:** Both queries take care of the fact that passenger can have multiple services per ticket or no services at all.

---

Now with your current schema

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT SUM(fare) 
          FROM passenger
         WHERE ticket_id = t.id) total_fare,
       (SELECT SUM(cost) 
          FROM service s JOIN passenger p
            ON s.passenger_id = p.id
         WHERE p.ticket_id = t.id) total_cost
  FROM ticket t
```

and

```
SELECT t.id, 
       p.fare total_fare,
       s.cost total_cost
FROM ticket t LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT ticket_id, SUM(fare) fare
    FROM passenger
   GROUP BY ticket_id
) p 
  ON t.id = p.ticket_id LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT p.ticket_id, SUM(cost) cost
    FROM service s  JOIN passenger p
      ON s.passenger_id = p.id
   GROUP BY p.ticket_id
) s
  ON t.id = s.ticket_id
```

---

**Just to get a grand total per ticket**

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT SUM(fare) 
          FROM passenger
         WHERE ticket_id = t.id) +
       (SELECT SUM(cost) 
          FROM service s JOIN passenger p
            ON s.passenger_id = p.id
         WHERE p.ticket_id = t.id) grand_total
  FROM ticket t
```

or

```
SELECT t.id, 
       p.fare + s.cost grand_total
FROM ticket t LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT ticket_id, SUM(fare) fare
    FROM passenger
   GROUP BY ticket_id
) p 
  ON t.id = p.ticket_id LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT p.ticket_id, SUM(cost) cost
    FROM service s  JOIN passenger p
      ON s.passenger_id = p.id
   GROUP BY p.ticket_id
) s
  ON t.id = s.ticket_id
```

Comment: @DipendraGurung See updated answer for solutions for your current table schema

Comment: Thanks! @Peterm, one thing i would like to add more, how can i add these two subqueries to get a single field as grand_total? Thanks! for your time. :)

Comment: @DipendraGurung You need just grand total, or you want to see total_fare, total_cost and grand_total?

Comment: I just want the grand total only.

Answer (score 3):

You can just join the three tables together, then you can do the SUMs directly without the subselect. You'll need to use `GROUP BY` to group by ticket.id if you want it per ticket.

Something like:

```
SELECT t.id, SUM(p.fare) AS total_far, SUM(s.cost) AS total_cost
FROM 
    ticket t, passenger p, service s
WHERE t.id = p.ticket_id AND s.passenger_id = p.id 
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Comment: Thanks! Space, when I run your query the total_cost was correctly summed up, but total_fare is not correct!

Comment: @DipendraGurung The total fare gets calculated in the same way as your question, so I don't see how that could be wrong here.

Comment: I don't think this or any other answer posted here works. If a passenger has more than one services, while calculating the fare, it will be added as many times as the number of  services.

Comment: @Jack If a passenger has two or more services then your total fare will fare * number of services per passenger. IMHO that's why it's wrong. More over it should be OUTER JOIN to services since person may not have services

Comment: @peterm, good point on the `OUTER JOIN` to catch when people don't have services. To avoid the other issue you could count the number of unique services and divide the total.

Comment: @SpaceDog Good idea to count distinct services, but the problem is that you most likely end up with an average per ticket

Comment: @peterm Yeah, I was wondering that -- I can't test at the moment but since we're grouping by ticket id already I would have thought that `(SUM(s.cost) \ COUNT(s.cost)) AS total_cost` would work. Although I suspect the subselect might be faster for a large amount of data.

Comment: @SpaceDog The problem is if a passenger (or passengers within a ticket) has(have) several services with the same price `COUNT(s.cost)` will be `1` instead of `N`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(fare) as total_fare,
    SUM(cost) as total_service_cost
FROM
    ticket
left join passenger ON ticket.id = passenger.ticket_id
left join service ON passenger.id = service.passenger_id
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `group by` :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
with fares as(
select p.id id, p.ticket_id ticket_id, sum(coalesce(s.cost,0)) cost
  from passenger p left outer join service s
       on p.id = s.passenger_id
 group by p.id, p.ticket_id)
select q.ticket_id, sum(f.cost), sum(q.fare), sum(f.cost + q.fare)
  from fares f inner join passenger q
       on f.id = q.id
 group by q.ticket_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(fare) as total_fare,
    SUM(cost) as total_cost as total_service_cost
FROM
    ticket
JOIN passenger ON passenger.ticket_id = ticket.id
JOIN service ON passenger.id = service.passenger_id
```

If you need to sum for each ticket then add `GROUP BY ticket.id`

Comment: is double 'as' allowed in the 3rd line of your query? I had an error running this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    t.code,
    sum(p.fare) as total_fare,
    sum(s.cost) as total_cost
from ticket as t
    inner join passenger as p on p.ticket_id = t.id
    inner join service as s on s.passenger_id = p.id
group by t.code
```