# Add/Subtract value to a value of a presiding cell value vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

[image]

I have a datagridview as one above. I need to get the balance i.e by adding or subtracting the values of Credit or debit to the value of the balance in the presiding row.

Comment: How do you supply data into your datagridview? you can have the calculation before inserting the data into `datagridview`

Comment: All entries except the balance are from a database

Comment: If you use a database query you can probably use a sub select to get the balances as well so you don't have to do anything application side. A bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201600/sql-sum-operation-of-multiple-subqueries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can do SUM(xxx) in your database query

2) Client-side - there are many ways, but here is how to sum values in one column and put result into a NumericUpDown.

```
Dim SumVal1 as int32
For ir = 0 to Me.dgw.rows.count - 1
    Dim dr as DataGridViewRow = me.dgw.rows(ir)
    SumVal1 += dr.Cell("Val1Column").value
next ir
Me.ResultNumericUpDown.Value = SumVal1
```

You can insert it into an extra row in a similar fashion, however, I'd be very careful about combining bound and unbound data in one DataGridView. If you can, avoid it. Either do data manipulation in query, or
do following step after data reading and before you bind data to dataGridView:

```
Dim ds as new dataSet
ds = DAL.MyDBreadFuncion(cmdText) '-- read data from database
Dim dt as new DataTable  '-- create new datatable to manipulate data
dt = ds.tables(0)
dt.rows.add()  '-- add an empty row

Dim SumVal1 as int32
For ir = 0 to dt.rows.count - 2   ' skip last row, keep it for results
    Dim dr as DataRow = dt.rows(ir)
    SumVal1 += dr("Val1Column")
next ir
dt.rows(dt.rows.count -1)("Val1Column") = SumVal1

Me.dgw.datasource = dt   ' add manipulated dataTable to DataGridView source
```

Comment: Worked fine.Thanks