# SQL summing the same column with different date conditions

Tags: sql

I'm using one table and am trying to sum total spend for two separate years, pulling from the same column.

Essentially I have a list of customers, and I'm trying to sum their 2018 spend, and their 2019 spend. I've tried a few different things, but I can't seem to get the "case when" function to work because once the 2018 spend condition is met and that value is populated, it won't sum for 2019, and vice versa—so I've got a total for 2018 OR 2019, but no customers are showing spend for both.

This is my query:

```
select * 
from
    (select 
         buyer_first_name, buyer_last_name, buyer_address_1, buyer_address_2,
         buyer_address_city, buyer_address_state, buyer_address_zip, buyer_email, buyer_phone_1,
         sum(case when sale_amount > 0 and year(sale_date) = 2018 then sale_amount end) as Spend18,
         sum(case when sale_amount > 0 and year(sale_date) = 2019 then sale_amount end) as Spend19
     from 
         database.table
     where 
         sale_date between date '2018-01-01' and date '2019-10-30'
     group by 
         buyer_first_name, buyer_last_name, buyer_address_1, buyer_address_2,
         buyer_address_city, buyer_address_state, buyer_address_zip, buyer_email, buyer_phone_1)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: i think you're looking for sub-selects. Separate out the case and where conditions into their own select statement and select on that instead. See here for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201600/sql-sum-operation-of-multiple-subqueries

Comment: Also called sub-queries https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery

Comment: btw, if Spend18  condition is met and calculated, what value you get under Spend19 for the same customer?

Comment: Anatoliy: I just get NULL for Spend19 in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt that your problem is with SQL syntax or a bug.  Your query *looks* like it should be doing what you want.

The issue is that those fields are not the same for *any* customer in the two years.  Try something like this:

```
select buyer_last_name
       sum(case when sale_amount > 0 and year(sale_date) = 2018 then sale_amount end) as Spend18,
       sum(case when sale_amount > 0 and year(sale_date) = 2019 then sale_amount end) as Spend19
from database.table
where sale_date between date '2018-01-01' and date '2019-10-30'
group by buyer_last_name;
```

I speculate that last names are unlikely to change.  If this works, you can start adding columns back to see where the problem columns are.

This is why databases are *normalized*.  Repeated data tends to get out of synch.

Comment: This was it!! Thank you!

Comment: @Caroline . . . If this solves your problem, you can consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's weird why you have such a problem and this really need to research. Frankly I would expect the same result you do. However you can bypass this by doing something like that (assuming you are using mysql):

```
sum(sale_amount * if(sale_amount > 0 and year(sale_date) = 2018, 1, 0)) as Spend18,
sum(sale_amount * if(sale_amount > 0 and year(sale_date) = 2019, 1, 0)) as Spend19
```

If all your sales are >=0 you can skip positive condition for sale amount

If this does not work, test select without grouping and see what's going on:

```
select sale_amount * if(sale_amount > 0 and year(sale_date) = 2018, 1, 0) as spend18,
       sale_amount * if(sale_amount > 0 and year(sale_date) = 2019, 1, 0) as spend19
from your_table;
```

Comment: This seems to be giving me the same problem—I have values for some customers in Spend18 and some in Spend 19, but never both.

Comment: this is weird, you need to select without grouping and see if data are populated, I edited the answer, see my last query

Comment: Appreciate your help.